# Can I use edamame pods to make a vegetable broth?

Tags: vegetables, broth, soybeans

I’m currently saving various vegetable scraps to make veggie broth. I have a bunch of leftover edamame pods that I would normally just compost, but I’m wondering if they would work well in my broth. Would that taste okay?

Comment: Sometimes edamame is served heavily salted as a snack. If your pods are covered in salt I would rinse them so they don't make the stock too salty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't expect them to have much effect on your broth either way.  The pod shells are fairly fibrous and don't have much flavor of their own.

Comment: Would they at least add more fiber to a broth? Thanks!

Comment: @Evan93 Unless you are cooking them into a pulp, no probably not. If you did cook them that far down, I highly doubt it would make for a tasty broth, probably quite the opposite. Things like these pod shells are far better used in compost, to make your garden soil more fertile. If you don't have a garden, or a composter, you should simply discard.

Answer (score 0):

yes, i reuse pods  to make like a broth, but with a bullion 1/2 cube , onions, and scallions , basil , and oregano fresh garlic, salt, and pepper, if your making small pot just for yourself like i do , you can use again the pods just suck on them one more time and then toss them in garbage or use in garden soil, they are tasty second time around, don't swallow though unless you have strong stomach, mixed in with broth ingredients you will love it

Comment: Welcome and thanks for sharing your thoughts. I noticed that you are suggesting a recipe that uses a bullion cube, however the asker wonders about making a vegetable broth from scratch, where the vegetables are creating the broth, not cooked on a broth.